# How to use TickMarkType.TimeWithSeconds with the CDN version

Tags: javascript, cdn, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I would like to be able to generate graphs with the x-axis of the form year-month-day hour:minute:second.

I saw in the documentation that you had to use tickMarkFormatter and that you had to define the constant TickMarkType.TimeWithSeconds but I don't understand where!

I don't use Typescript, just an html page with the .js library imported in a script tag, could someone help me ?

Once that's done, I'll just have to add the time on my data this way?

```
lineSeries.setData([
    { time: '2020-04-11 20:10:00', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2020-04-12 20:10:10', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2020-04-13 20:10:20', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2020-04-14 20:10:30', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2020-04-15 20:10:40', value: 74.43 },
    { time: '2020-04-16 20:10:50', value: 80.01 },

]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, juste need to use timestamp instead of date format.